# Is this chatty question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I asked my first question: [Limitations for concurrent login of the same user?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16854/limitations-for-concurrent-login-of-the-same-user) and I am worried that it turned up to be too chatty (I took time to read Faq page about questions)

My posted question is rather simple: Is there any limitations for concurrent login of same user? I provided some additional info to explain source of my problem. I believe this was mistake because now people are ignoring my original question and they are focusing on some of my 'not-so-good' practice.

What i'm asking here is: Is my question asked in the wrong way?

And in addition: Is it ok to ask a question which in advance you consider to be unanswerable even if it looks nice and simple? (I have tons of those)

I also hope that this meta question falls under first of [The 7 Essential Meta Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta).

Comment: I'd like to say, thanks for bringing this up on meta and taking the time to research. :)

Answer (score 3):

I've thought about this a bit. At first, I would have said that is a perfectly legit question; it is a problem you're facing that has a definitive answer.

However, I'm now leaning towards this being something you might ask in **chat** rather than in a question. My reasoning is... as interesting as it is, I don't think it is particularly constructive. I don't believe this scenario is recommended and knowing the answer doesn't really help anything.

> Q: My friends and I were poking a starving alligator with a stick. How many times can I poke the alligator before he gets angry?

A: Don't poke the alligator with a stick.

Comment: Knowing the answer will help me to sleep better. Now seriously, you confirmed my fears after I received first answer and few comments. Now another question arises: What to do about original  question or how to make it die with some dignity? I will certainly be much more careful with next one.

Comment: @VedranRasol The end result has not been a bad question, in fact it has demonstrated the problems with sharing admin accounts. I think it's fine to stay as it is. Just follow the guidance on asking questions in the [faq] and if you have any questions about using the site we welcome them here on Meta.

Comment: @VedranRasol Also, a pointer that your question is useful are the upvotes on it. You have 3 at the time I write this which is a good sign.

Comment: @Vedran: I gave it a +1 before you asked this on meta. :) Alex brings up a good point about showing the real issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the hate with the "chatty comments", surely as long as the outcome and resolution is clearly pointed somewhere, it could sometimes be helpful to see the processes that went along to see that conclusion. Why would you want to get rid of that?

Comment: As Kit pointed out: described process is not best practice (not even close). Problem is that question in title (relevant or not - to be discussed) is ignored by users and everyone is focused on process. But if I just asked one line question - I doubt that someone will take second look at it.

Comment: @James: I think the problem is that you end up with a lot of noise. It helps to clean up the comments and move the information into the question and/or answer. Then, when someone comes looking for the answer it is easy for them to read and understand.